# Find a hashtag in a string in php

Tags: php

I would like to add a link around my string which is

```
    "My new Tweet **#new** this is cool".
```

And I would like to get the hashtag #new to wrap into a link.

After that, I'll get :

```
    "My new Tweet <a href="http://twitter.com/search/%23new">new</a> this is cool.
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = "My new Tweet **#new** this is cool".
$linked_string = preg_replace('/\*\*(\#(.*?))\*\*/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/search/$1">$2</a>', $string);
```

Comment: You'll need to URL encode the hashtag in the `href` and HTML entity encode the hashtag inside the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your hastags contain only letters and numbers, you can use the following code:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\*\*#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*\*/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/search/%23$1">$1</a>', $string);
```

You can easily change the content of the regex as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but this was an example, I want to change the link but not always write new, but the content of the hashtag.
You know what I mean ?
Thanks

Comment: This will introduce an XSS vulnerability if the hashtags are user-controllable (which is a real possibility).

Comment: You forgot a '+' after the [a-zA-Z0-9] group

Comment: you're right, I corrected it on my test file but not here. Thanks.

Comment: @Zaidar, the code works and does what you asked.. there was a little error at first, try it again

Comment: drrcknlsn: Please explain, how could a range of [a-zA-Z0-9] introduce a XSS vunerability?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thanks, but I did what you said, but I don't understandd why my browser doesn't display the #new as a link.

Comment: @nyson: That's an answer-imposed restricted regex that lorenzo suggests may be changed at the OP's discretion.  If the OP were to implement this solution and find the regex too restrictive (and change it), it's very likely that it will introduce an XSS hole.

Comment: I would prefer the range to be [\w\d], as this will make characters like åäö work.

Comment: well, as I said that is a basic regex that could be changed reflecting @Zaidar's needs.

Comment: @nyson:  With proper encoding, the range can be as liberal as it needs to be (even `.+`).  See my answer.

Comment: @lorenzo.marcon:  Your answer provides no protection against potential XSS, though.  You need to be using `urlencode()` and `htmlentities()` to protect against this, should he decide to change your regex.

Comment: well, that's not the main focus of the question, but thanks anyway for pointing that out. That regex was strict enough for @Zaidar's needs, I suppose.

Comment: /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ I found this one which work ! Thanks everyone for help !

Comment: You want to keep the double stars before and after the link? **..**

Comment: @Zaidar: lol.. it works until you run across text like "I'm #1!  Don't be jealous!"

Answer (score 1):

This would probably do it:

```
$yourString = 'My new Tweet **#new** this is cool';

$yourString = preg_replace_callback('/\*\*(#(.+?))\*\*/', function($matches) {
    $html = '<a href="http://twitter.com/search/%s">%s</a>';
    return sprintf($html, urlencode($matches[1]), htmlentities($matches[2]));
}, $yourString);
```

Comment: how do I apply that on a string ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It applies itself to the string you give it (`$yourString`).

Comment: ok, I didn't saw all the code. But I don't understand why it doesn't display as a link on my browser. Thanks for help, really !

Comment: @Zaidar:  The code works, and does what you asked for.  You'll have to show what you tried and what the result/errors were, or nobody can help you.

Comment: /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
I found this one which work !
Thanks everyone for help !

Comment: actually the one you say it works is different than the one you marked as accepted answer..